# removing part of string UPDATED

Tags: javascript, string

www.powersource.se

The last link, "Add some stuff" doesn't work properly. It's supposed to add a bit of text when you press it and then remove the text when you press it again. I've made the add-part work, but I haven't managed to make the remove-part.

```
function add_module(title, text)
{
container = document.getElementById('text-main');
the_text ='<div class="text-header" id="added-text-header">' + title + '</div><div id="added-text">' + text + '</div>';
if(container.innerHTML != container.innerHTML + the_text)
{
container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + the_text;
}else if(container.div.innerHTML == container.innerHTML + the_text)
{
text_container = container.getElementById('added-text-header');
parent = text_container.parentNode;
parent.removeChild(text_container);
text_container = container.getElementById('added-text');
parent = text_container.parentNode;
parent.removeChild(text_container);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using + to add text in. That's how JavaScript concatenates two strings.

The problem comes when you try to use - to remove. That won't work. The minus sign is for subtracting numbers, not for taking something away from a string.

I'd suggest using jQuery or another JavaScript library that has good cross-browser DOM manipulation. When you insert more text in, use a function to add a chunk of HTML. Use the p tag: `<p>some text</p>`. Then you'll be able to hunt down the p tags and delete the last one.

Comment: That is kind of an intuitive use of - for strings.  It really should work that way.

Comment: What if there were two instances of the substring you're trying to "subtract"?  Pretty tough to come up with something that makes sense.  I don't even like the `+`, though, so maybe I'm not the one to comment.

Comment: @stimms you get into some odd ambiguities there however. For example, does `-` subtract the right operand from every occurrence in the string? Just the first? Just the last?

Comment: "That is kind of an intuitive use of - for strings. It really should work that way." I'd make the other case--reusing the plus sign for string concatenation causes all kinds of problems. Neither + nor - should have anything to do with strings.

Comment: i now have set the code to remove the div, though it still don't wanna work :(

Comment: "if(container.innerHTML == container.innerHTML + the_text)" will never be true unless the_text is an empty string. I think you should work through some tutorials that show items being added and removed.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `string1 + string2` you're actually creating a brand new string, `+` is just shorthand for "mash these two together."

If you want to be able to add and remove that text you'll have to do it another way. The real issue is that once you've concatenated the strings together you have no idea which part of the string is the original, and which part is the user's.

In jQuery you can use DOM manipulation to better handle this. First I would put your div tags with the text-header and the text inside your container, but leave them empty. That way you don't have to create them on the fly. Then (assuming your text div has a class of "text-body"):

```
var textHeader = $("#text-main .text-header");
var textBody = $("#text-main .text-body");

//If the header doesn't contain the title set it, otherwise remove it
if(textHeader.text() != title) {
    textHeader.text(title)
} else {
    textHeader.text("");
}

//If the text body doesn't contain the text set it, otherwise remove it
if(textBody.text() != text) {
    textBody.text(text)
} else {
    textBody.text("");
}
```